# Sending multiple and and different attachments through VBA and Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm by no means an expert and I want to send the multiple and different attachments (e.g. Person1 receives BOTH attch.1 and attach.2; Person2 receives attch.3 and attch. 5 etc).

My code:

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim dlApp As Outlook.Application
  Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  olMail.To = what_address
  olMail.Subject = subject_line
  olMail.Body = mail_body
  olMail.Send
End Sub

Sub SendMassEmail()
Dim mail_body_message As String
Dim title As String
  row_number = 1
  Do
    DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1

    mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("D2")
    title = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", title)
    Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "This is a test", mail_body_message)
  Loop Until row_number = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code requires some work but the snippet below should help with adding multiple attachments.  I have tried to add annotations that might be helpful.

Please note that the full path for each attachment must be known.

For example:
C:\TestFolder\TestSubfolder\TestFile.txt

You should be able to use the same looping concept to traverse across columns to handle multiple emails.  It would be difficult to suggest the exact looping to be used without knowing the structure of your spreadsheet.

```
Sub GenerateEmails()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim myRange As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'This will only generate a single email with multiple attachments.
'You will need another loop or something similar to process multiple emails the loop could
'be similar to the loop below that use offset to go down rows but instead
'you will offest across columns
With OutMail
        'I have used hard coded cell ranges to define the values but you can use other
        'methods.
        .Subject = Range("A1").Value
        .To = Range("A2").Value
        .CC = Range("A3").Value
        .Body = Range("A4").Value
        'This is where you list of attachments will start
        Set myRange = Range("A5")
        'Keep going down one cell until no more attachment values are provided
        Do Until myRange.Value = ""
            'The value here needs to be the full attachment path including file name and extension
            .Attachments.Add (myRange.Value)
            'Set the range to be the next cell down
            Set myRange = myRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        'This displays the email without sending.
        .Display
        'Once the code is correct you can use the .Send instead to actually send the emails.
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Shimeon, I sincere appreciate your response and I'm so sorry that it took me 3 years to say 'thanks!'. i just saw this..Thanks!

Comment: lol.  No problem, I guess you figured out your code problem some other way.